# Comparing strings using '==' and 'is'

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Types for which “is” keyword may be equivalent to equality operator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218308/types-for-which-is-keyword-may-be-equivalent-to-equality-operator-in-python)
>   [Python “is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/python-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

Hi.

I have a question which perhaps might enlighten me on more than what I am asking.

Consider this:

```
>>> x = 'Hello'
>>> y = 'Hello'
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
True
```

I have always used the comparison operator. Also I read that `is` compares the memory address and hence in this case, returns `True`

So my question is, is this another way to compare variables in Python? If yes, then why is this not used?

Also I noticed that in C++, if the variables have the same value, their memory addresses are different.

```
{ int x = 40; int y = 40; cout << &x, &y; }
0xbfe89638, 0xbfe89634
```

What is the reason for Python having the same memory addresses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to check for equality in Python: `==` and `is`. `==` will check the value, while `is` will check the identity. In almost every case, if `is` is true, then `==` must be true.

Sometimes, Python (specifically, CPython) will optimize values together so that they have the same identity. This is especially true for short strings. Python realizes that 'Hello' is the same as 'Hello' and since strings are immutable, they become the same through string interning / string pooling.

See a related question: [Python: Why does ("hello" is "hello") evaluate as True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392433/python-why-is-hello-is-hello)

Answer (score 12):

This is an implementation detail and absolutely not to be relied upon. `is` compares identities, not values. Short strings are interned, so they map to the same memory address, but this doesn't mean you should compare them with `is`. Stick to `==`.

Comment: Aah I see. I will stick to `==`, however I wanted to be sure what I was doing was correct.

Comment: Whether short strings are interned or not is dependent upon the interpreter implementation you're using - you can't ever rely on it.

Answer (score 8):

This is because of a Python feature called [`String interning`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) which is a method of storing **only one**  copy of each **distinct** string value.

Comment: +1 for answering the question instead of - out of habit, I guess - saying "don't" :)

Comment: I was looking for this term. Thank you, I will read up. This answer what I am asking.

Comment: You've answered the last question, but not the first two.

Answer (score 1):

In Python both strings and integers are immutable therefore you ***can*** cache them. Integers in the range of ´-5´ to ´256´ and small strings(don't know the exact size atm) get cached, therefore they are the same object. `x` and `y` are only names that refer to these objects.

Also `==` compares for equals values, while `is` compares for object identity. `None` `True` and `False` are global objects, for example you can rebind `False` to `True`.

The following shows that not every thing is being cached:

```
x = 'Test' * 2000
y = 'Test' * 2000

>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
False

>>> x = 10000000000000
>>> y = 10000000000000
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
False
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, variables are just names that point to some object (and they can point to the same object). In C++, variables also define the actual memory that is reserved for them; this is why they have distinct memory addresses.

About Python string interning and differences between the two comparison operators, see [carl's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403964/comparing-strings-using-and-is/3403990#3403990).

Comment: Yes I figured it out now. Thanks.