# Weird behaviour of id function in cpython

Tags: python, python-2.7

I did the following:

```
>>> a=10
>>> id(a)
31817408L
>>>
>>> id(10)
31817408L
```

So, we can see that id(a) equals id(10)

Now,i do

```
>>>a='what is this'
>>> id(a)
   35412416L
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> id('what is this')
   31951968L
```

why in this case id(a) not equal to id('what is this')?
What is actually happening behind the scenes?

Comment: Other related question: [Types for which “is” keyword may be equivalent to equality operator in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3218308/364696)

Answer (score 2):

Different IDs mean different addresses in memory, so your two 'what is this' strings are truly two strings, even though they store the same value. On the other hand, Python optimizes the frequently-used integers so that all the occurrences point to the same object in memory. And fortunately, that object is immutable, so you can't say 10=9. If you choose an infrequently-used integer, you can see what's going on:

`>>> a=555555`
`>>> id(a)`
`44506456L`
`>>> id(555555)`
`44506528L`

Comment: Please also explain this in your answer: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/423197/

Comment: @NehalJWani, I don't follow you. That's exactly the same phenomenon, but with frequently-used integer 123 instead of frequently-used integer 10.

Comment: I am using strings in the paste (not numbers), and for the first case, the id is same for `a` and `b`, but for the second case, the id is not same for `a` and `b`.

Comment: So my question is, why does python think that `'123'` is a frequently used string, but `'what is this'` is not?

Comment: One more query: if i do  a=555555  and b=555555, i was expecting that both will point to memory address of 555555 and thereby resulting the increase in refcount for 555555  by 1. So total refcount for 555555   is 2.Is that correct? But then how come memory address in above examples are different?

Comment: @NehalJWani: Sorry, I missed the fact that you were using strings. I don't know what Python's criteria are for deciding which strings (or integers) are frequently used. You could look it up, or you could experiment and see. But it doesn't really matter. As long as the objects in question are immutable, Python is entitled to optimize the references to them in any way it wants. It can change its scheme across versions of Python or across phases of the moon or whatever.

Comment: @fsociety: As far as I know, Python has only two optimization (or lack-of-optimization) patterns: If the integer belongs to a hardwired set of frequently-used integers, Python optimizes. If not, it doesn't. Apparently, 55555 is not in that set. So I would expect that every single instance of it would be stored at a different memory address. In principle, Python could notice that 555555 was suddenly being used a lot, and add 555555 to the set, but I doubt it does that. To explore a little more, try `a=555555; b=a; id(a), id(b)`.